# XPages: convert content from existing Notes documents (sections and tabbed tables)

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

We are converting a web app to XPages, but we have concerns on the content conversion.

From initial testing, we noted that sections and tabbed tables are not rendered in the xpage version of the form.  Is there a way to convert content so sections and/or tabbed tables are displayed properly?

Any HTML/MIME conversion magic available or anything else not too complicated that can be done???

Comment: are you talking about sections and tables created by users in a rich text field or sections and tables added to a form?

Comment: Thomas, I'm talking about sections and tables added through the Notes client, in a rich text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a workaround

You can use the old way of displaying a document. by just pointing to the document, like this
/server/db.nsf/0/6facf027e4bf1c3bc1257dd30042d108?openDocument

If you do it like this you will get working tabs and sections.
 you can  display the rich text field from the document in this way using an iframe in your xpages.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Ben, you might want to call Geniisoft. The owner, Ben, is an expert at Rich Text to HTML conversion and has several products that will help you.http://www.geniisoft.com/

Comment: I don't really need two way conversion.  The data will be viewed and edited through the web once the application goes live.  No need to look nice in Notes