# How to display and work with tabbed table in XPages?

Tags: xpages, rtf, tabbed

I have database where all documents were created by Lotus Notes client. Documents contain Rich text field with tabbed tables with text and attachments on every tab.

Now I want to show documents with XPages. But tabbed tables are not visible in XPages.

How can I display Rich text field with tabbed table in XPages?

Comment: It is a good question. So add more details and follow basic rules http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to prevent downvotes and/or close.

Comment: I have database, all documents created in client LN. In documents there are tabbed tables with text and attachments on every tab. Tabbed tables created in Rich Text. Now I want to convert LN documents in web with XPages. But have one problem. I can't display tabbed tables in XPages. Please, help

Comment: added your comment to question (and do so with future updates).

Comment: btw: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031748/xpages-convert-content-from-existing-notes-documents-sections-and-tabbed-table

Comment: Thank you very much! I pointing to the document, like this /server/db.nsf/0/6facf027e4bf1c3bc1257dd30042d108?openDocument. But nothing.

Comment: Please, update your question: what you try, with what result and so on... "But nothing" is too general to give any advice.

Comment: I pointing to the document, like this /server/db.nsf/0/6facf027e4bf1c3bc1257dd30042d108?openDocument. But tabbed table displayed as always: first row is a header of tab, second row displays attachments and text, third row again header but another tab and so on

Answer (score 1):

The answer isn't as straight forwarded as you would like and involved some wizardry. There are several moving parts. The first is the quality of the RTF-HTML conversion. I superstrongly suggest you give [Ben a call](http://www.geniisoft.com/). In case he doesn't handle tabbed tables (which are a beast), these are the steps to get a solution (I hope the <strike>force</strike> Javascript is strong with you):

- Familiarize yourself with the Table handling and rendering. To do so, open the RichText field on its own in the browser. The trick is the ?OpenField command as documented by [Carl](http://www.iminstant.com/iminstant/iminstant.nsf/d6plinks/ctyr-7h6s6r).
- In that HTML you can click on the various tabs to show that content, look at the URL and the source to learn about the exact syntax (which AFAIK isn't documented - or the documentation is well hidden)
- By now you should have an idea how to identify a tabbed table by its HTML markup. Try to construct a Dojo selector or a JQuery (whatever is your poison).
- Now show your page **without** the RichText field, but place a placeholder `<div id="RTPlaceholder" />` where you want to show your content (or place a dijit panel there).
- Use an Ajax call to `?OpenField` to get the content. With your query expression you check for tabbed tables - if none there, just render the content
- If you found a tabbed table, you construct a dijit tabbed table (or a UI framework of your choice equivalent) and make one call per tab to fill them. Some clever queries are needed (you don't want the surrounding table, but only tab-label and content).

That's the general direction. So Step 1: a little chat with Ben. As usual the devil is in the details, so you need to be brave.

Memento bene:

`RichText > HTML => false;
HTML > RichText => false;
HMTL != RichText => true;`

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did 2 items. I read documented by Carl and open document like this /server/db.nsf/0/6facf027e4bf1c3bc1257dd30042d108/Body?OpenField&TableRow=1.2. That means 1-first table and 2-third tab. Now I should do another advices, but may be you help me a little